# Why I am unable to to dynamically add more websockets endpoints and handlers using spring boot?

Tags: websocket, endpoint, spring-websocket

```
@Service
public class StreamServiceImpl implements StreamService {

    @Autowired
    private WebSocketConfig webSocketConfig;

    @Override
    public void registerNewWebSocketHandlerForArtist(String artistName) {
        webSocketConfig
            .registry
            .addHandler(new SocketHandler(), "/websocket/liveAudioStream/" + artistName)
            .setAllowedOrigins("*");
    }
    
}
```

WebSocketConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    public WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry;

    /**
     * This function defines the following websocket endpoints.
     * 1. 'ws://localhost:8080/liveAudioStream'.
     * 
     * @param registry registers the url patterns and allowed origins for an endpoint.
     */
    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        this.registry = registry;

        registry
            .addHandler(new SocketHandler(), "/websocket/liveAudioStream")
            .setAllowedOrigins("*");
    }

}
```

After this I am using postman to connect to the new endpoint I just added. But the connect operation does not succeed.
Please suggest some way out for dynamically adding new endpoints and handlers to web socket during runtime in spring boot.